# On normal lines and centers of curvature at points where the curvature is maximum/minimum

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Let $\alpha(s)$ be a plane curve.

I need to check that the normal line to $\alpha$ at $s$ is orthogonal to the curve that is determined by the centers of curvature on the points in which the curvature of $\alpha$ is maximized or minimized.

I think I could do this if I was actually given the curve, but I can't see any clear way to attack the problem as it stands now.

Comment: That sentence is not at all clear in its intent. Is this what you mean? Let $\beta$ be the curve traced out by the centers of curvature of $\alpha$. Then the normal line to $\alpha$ at points of max/min curvature is orthogonal to $\beta$.

Comment: Hmm, the curve $\beta$ has vanishing tangent vector (indeed, often exhibits cuspidal behavior) at the points corresponding to the center of curvature coming from a point of max/min curvature. I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: What's true is that *except* for points of max/min curvature, the normal line to $\alpha$ at $s$ is *also* normal to $\beta$ at the corresponding center of curvature. Write down a parametrization of $\beta$ and prove this. :)

Comment: @Ted Sorry for not being clear, a more precise statement of the problem would indeed be "Let $β$ be the curve traced out by the centers of curvature of $\alpha$. Then the normal line to $\alpha$ at points of max/min curvature is orthogonal to $β$". So, I took your advice, and wrote down $β = (x(s) - \frac{y'(s)}{k(s)}, y(s) + \frac{x'(s)}{k(s)})$, and took the dot product of $β$ with $n(s) = (-y'(s), x'(s))$, the vector that spans the normal line at $s$. I got the result of $x'(s)y(s) + x(s)y'(s) + \frac{1}{k(s)}$. Am I meant to prove this is zero or is there something else I'm not seeing?

Comment: It's really better to work with vectors and Frenet equations! But the statement is, in fact, false. $\beta'(s) = 0$ (so there is no tangent) at points corresponding to critical points of $k(s)$. Oh, and being orthogonal to the curve $\beta$ means being orthogonal to its tangent vector at the point!!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I understand now why the original statement is false. Now I'm trying to prove "except for points of max/min curvature, the normal line to $\alpha$ at $s$ is also normal to $β$ at the corresponding center of curvature.". So, like I said earlier, I took the dot product of the vectors. and using the Frenet equations and a little bit of regrouping, I got $β(s)\cdot n(s) = \cfrac{x(s)x''(s) + y(s)y''(s) + 1}{k(s)}$, and it's not quite clear to me how that is $0$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Oh, I see now I wasn't aware of what orthogonality to a curve meant. I'll try to fix my attempt of the comment above.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. So it turns out all of this was just a more convoluted way of saying "if $\alpha$ is a plane curve, then the tangent lines to the evolute, $β$, are orthogonal to $\alpha$", which one can prove by taking the derivative of $β$, that is, $β'(s) = \cfrac{n(s)k'(s)}{(k(s))^2}$. Since clearly $n(s)$ is orthogonal to $\alpha$, the problem is done.

Comment: Oh, and of course, one has to note that the statement is only valid at the points where $k(s)$ isn't maximized/minimized, like you did. Thanks!

Comment: Great. You can refer to the exercise in my text on involute/evolute, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered in the comments.